# Trying to compile xf86drm.h example

Tags: c, drawing, framebuffer, libc

On this page https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dvdhrm/docs/master/drm-howto/modeset.c someone has published an example on how to properly use the drm api.

I downloaded the source file compiled it with `gcc -I/usr/include/drm/ modeset.h -o modeset`, marked it as executeable `chmod +x modeset` and launched it `./modeset`

Output:

```
michael@lord:~/Documents/cpp/modeset$ ./modeset 
./modeset: line 1: $'gpchC014\310\b\032\231\253\267+\277\331\022\225I\021': command not found
./modeset: line 17: syntax error near unexpected token `$'\375?\250\001\177\001\001''
./modeset: line 17: `ø?¨
                              ø?¨
                                  ø?¨ø?¨0ø?¨2ø?¨4ø?¨6ø?¨8ø?¨9ø?¨:ø?¨;ø?¨<ø?¨=ø?¨>ø?¨Pø?¨Rø?¨Tø?¨Vø?¨Xø?¨Zø?¨\ø?¨^ø?¨`ø?¨bø?¨dø?¨fø?¨hø?¨jø?¨lø?¨nø?¨ø?¨ø?¨ø?¨ø?¨ø?¨ø?¨ø?¨ø?¨ ø?¨¢ø?¨¤ø?¨¦ø?¨¨ø?¨ªø?¨¬ø?¨®ø?¨°ø?¨±ø?¨²ø?¨³ø?¨´ø?¨µø?¨¶ø?¨·ø?¨¸ø?¨¹ø?¨ºø?¨»ø?¨¼ø?¨½ø?¨¾ø?¨¿ø?¨ðø?¨òø?¨ôø?¨öø?¨øø?¨úø?¨üø?¨þø?¨ù?¨ù?¨ù?¨ù?¨ù?¨ù?¨ù?¨ù?¨ù?¨ù?¨Aù?¨Cù?¨Eù?¨Gù?¨Iù?¨Kù?¨Mù?¨Où?¨aù?¨cù?¨eù?¨gù?¨iù?¨kù?¨mù?¨où?¨qù?¨sù?¨uù?¨wù?¨yù?¨{ù?¨}ù?¨ù?¨ù?¨ù?¨ù?¨ù?¨ù?¨ù?¨ù?¨ù?¨Áù?¨Ãù?¨Åù?¨Çù?¨Éù?¨Ëù?¨Íù?¨Ïù?¨Ñù?¨Óù?¨Õù?¨×ù?¨Ùù?¨Ûù?¨Ýù?¨ßù?¨ñù?¨óù?¨õù?¨÷ù?¨ùù?¨ûù?¨ýù?¨ÿù?¨ú?¨ú?¨ú?¨ú?¨   ú?¨
ú?¨ú?¨1ú?¨3ú?¨5ú?¨7ú?¨9ú?¨;ú?¨=ú?¨?ú?¨Qú?¨Sú?¨Uú?¨Wú?¨Yú?¨[ú?¨]ú?¨_ú?¨qú?¨sú?¨uú?¨wú?¨yú?¨{ú?¨}ú?¨ú?¨ú?¨ú?¨ú?¨ú?¨ú?¨ú?¨ú?¨ú?¨¡ú?¨¢ú?¨£ú?¨¤ú?¨¦ú?¨¨ú?¨ªú?¨¬ú?¨®ú?¨Àú?¨Âú?¨Äú?¨Æú?¨Èú?¨Êú?¨Ìú?¨Îú?¨ðú?¨òú?¨ôú?¨öú?¨øú?¨úú?¨üú?¨þú?¨û?¨û?¨û?¨û?¨û?¨û?¨û?¨û?¨ û?¨"û?¨$û?¨&û?¨(û?¨*û?¨,û?¨.û?¨Pû?¨Rû?¨Tû?¨Vû?¨Xû?¨Zû?¨\û?¨^û?¨`û?¨bû?¨dû?¨fû?¨hû?¨jû?¨lû?¨nû?¨û?¨û?¨û?¨û?¨û?¨û?¨û?¨û?¨Ðû?¨Òû?¨Ôû?¨Öû?¨Øû?¨Úû?¨Üû?¨Þû?¨àû?¨âû?¨äû?¨æû?¨èû?¨êû?¨ìû?¨îû?¨ðû?¨òû?¨ôû?¨öû?¨øû?¨úû?¨üû?¨þû?¨ü?¨ü?¨ü?¨ü?¨ü?¨ü?¨ü?¨ü?¨Pü?¨Rü?¨Tü?¨Vü?¨Xü?¨Zü?¨\ü?¨^ü?¨pü?¨rü?¨tü?¨vü?¨xü?¨zü?¨|ü?¨~ü?¨ü?¨ü?¨ü?¨ü?¨ü?¨ü?¨ü?¨ü?¨°ü?¨²ü?¨´ü?¨¶ü?¨¸ü?¨ºü?¨¼ü?¨½ü?¨¾ü?¨¿ü?¨Ðü?¨Ñü?¨Òü?¨Óü?¨Ôü?¨Õü?¨Öü?¨×ü?¨Øü?¨Ùü?¨Úü?¨Ûü?¨Üü?¨Ýü?¨Þü?¨ßü?¨àü?¨áü?¨âü?¨ãü?¨äü?¨æü?¨èü?¨éü?¨ëü?¨ìü?¨íü?¨îü?¨ïü?¨ ý?¨"ý?¨$ý?¨%ý?¨&ý?¨'ý?¨(ý?¨)ý?¨*ý?¨+ý?¨,ý?¨-ý?¨.ý?¨/ý?¨@ý?¨Aý?¨Bý?¨Dý?¨Fý?¨Gý?¨Hý?¨Iý?¨Jý?¨Lý?¨Ný?¨pý?¨rý?¨tý?¨vý?¨xý?¨yý?¨zý?¨{ý?¨|ý?¨~ý?¨ý?¨ý?¨ý?¨ý?¨ý?¨ý?¨ý?¨ý?¨ý?¨ý?¨¡ý?¨£ý?¨¥ý?¨§ý?¨©ý?¨«ý?¨¬ý?¨­ý?¨®ý?¨Àý?¨Âý?¨Äý?¨Æý?¨Èý?¨Êý?¨Ìý?¨Îý?¨ðý?¨òý?¨ôý?¨öý?¨÷ý?¨øý?¨ùý?¨úý?¨ûý?¨üý?¨ýý?¨ÿý?¨þ?¨þ?¨þ?¨þ?¨þ?¨þ?¨þ?¨þ?¨þ?¨?¨þ?¨þ?¨þ?¨ þ?¨"þ?¨#þ?¨$þ?¨%þ?¨&þ?¨(þ?¨*þ?¨+þ?¨,þ?¨-þ?¨.þ?¨/þ?¨@þ?¨Aþ?¨Bþ?¨Cþ?¨Eþ?¨ß@¨@¨@¨@¨@¨@¨@¨@¨@¨@¨Þ@¨ @¨Gþ?¨Hþ?¨Jþ?¨Lþ?¨Nþ?¨`þ?¨bþ?¨dþ?¨fþ?¨hþ?¨jþ?¨lþ?¨nþ?¨ þ?¨¢þ?¨¤þ?¨¦þ?¨¨þ?¨ªþ?¨¬þ?¨­þ?¨®þ?¨¯þ?¨'
^[[?1;2c^[[?1;2c
```

I do not understand this low level framebuffer example so I am a bit lost right now. The web is also not revealing any docs. Some basic hints about what's happening here would be enough.

I am also using xorg server.

Comment: You usually don't compile header files directly, but use them in a translation unit (`.cpp`) file with the `#include ...` preprocessor directive? Also `gcc`is used to compile plain c code, to compile for c++ use `g++` instead (thus I removed the [tag:c++] tag from your question).

Answer (score 0):

The file you are invoking seems not to be a valid ELF executable, bash tries to process it as a bash script and fails. You can check for sure by using `file` command, e.g. `file modeset`.

Check for the errors during your GCC build. Note that you try to compile `modeset.h`, not `modeset.c`.